# Codeigniter Post not accepting string URL

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I try to send an ajax post with URLs but it returns 403 forbidden, it works on my localhost but it does not work when deployed online (LAMP)

Form Code

```
<form id="Links">
  <input type="url" name="link1" id="link1" />
  <input type="url" name="link2" id="link2" />
  <input type="button" value="submit" id="submitLink" />
</form>
```

Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function()({
   $("#submitLink").click(function(){
        $.post("http://mysite.com/mycontroller/myfunction", $("#Links").serialized(), function(data){
            alert("success!");
        });
   });
});
```

PHP CI Function

```
public function myfunction()
{
    print_r($this->input->post());
    die();   
}
```

Viewing the ajax post on firebug console.. it shows 403 forbidden.. in online deployment.. but it works on localhost.

P.S.

My global xss filtering in config is set to false

Comment: Can you open the ajax url itself in the browser?

Comment: @Shomz Yes, it is a blank page

Comment: Hm, can you give the url?

Comment: @Shomz i cannot give it publicly... this is on the admin side of the web app

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you more then - I wanted to mess with it in the Network area of Dev tools.

Comment: Maybe a problem with the post data being sent? Try sending the post data via a normal form with `action="http://mysite.com/mycontroller/myfunction" method="post"` instead if ajax to see if it gives the same result.

Comment: don't you think you need to put **method='post'** in your form? like `<form id="Links" method='post'>`

Comment: @Samutz, I also tried submitting it as a regular form, it does not return 403, but the post vars are appeared to be empty.

Comment: @PawCabelin, it does not need to put method post because it is implemented as ajax post. You already instructed the form submission as post on your jquery post.

Comment: Maybe the LAMP server has a problem with HTML5? Try changing the url inputs to text.

Comment: server logs might help? check your htaccess settings too

Comment: what about index.php i mean you can try like this  http://mysite.com/index.php/mycontroller/myfunction. What happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Their are following things which need to be consider.

- Check the controller and method is present
- Is any restriction applied through .htaccess
- Check file permissions for reading and writing.

Comment: if controller is wrong, i should have 404 error, and if there is a restriction in.htaccess my other functions and ajax call shall not be working.. and if i don't have the correct file permissions, then my other functions should not be working. But everything is working.. except this